# Working with PHP OR/AND

Tags: php, html, mysql, search, mysqli

I have the following query:

```
 $get_crs_mysqli = "select * from courses where course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() AND ((course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%') 
    AND ((course_duration = '" . $duration1 . "' AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%') 
      OR (course_duration = '" . $duration2 . "' AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%')
OR (course_duration = '" . $duration3 . "' AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%') 
OR (course_delivery2 = '" . $delivery2 . "' AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%') 
OR (course_guarantee = '" . $guarantee1 . "' AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%')
OR (course_guarantee = '" . $guarantee2 . "' AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%')
OR (course_city = '" . $city . "' AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%')
OR (course_subc1 = '" . $category1 . "' AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%')
OR (course_subc2 = '" . $category2 . "' AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%')
OR (course_subc3 = '" . $category3 . "' AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%')
OR (course_subc4 = '" . $category4 . "' AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%')
OR (course_subc5 = '" . $category5 . "' AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%')
OR (course_delivery2 = '" . $delivery2 . "' AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%')

OR (course_delivery = '" . $delivery1 . "' AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%'))) ORDER BY course_date1 ASC LIMIT  $position, $item_per_page";
```

what essentially happen is that a user search for a course, and then when they apply the optional search filter, it gets revised as to reflect the filter. For instance, they search all html, and it loads all html, and if they select duration 1 than it should only show html courses with 1 duration.

At its current state, when an optional filter is selected, it remains intact, and if I change this

```
(course_duration = '" . $duration1 . "' AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%')
```

to

```
(course_duration = '" . $duration1 . "' OR course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%')
```

then it shows all courses with a duration 1, and completly disregard the html query

below is an example with picture:
[image]

Comment: Yes, thats what it is supposed to do, and why there are different words 'OR' and 'AND'

Comment: I think i work it out incorrectly. It suppose to populate the results first based on the search result of the and user and has an option if a user selects a filter than it narrows the option as to reflect that filter, like in this example html then checking duration1 should only populate courses with html and duration1, if duration2 is check then with duration2

Comment: any help or hint will be appreciated

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put arbitrary user data directly into a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all it would better to rewrite query to more readable variant:

```
$get_crs_mysqli = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM courses 
    WHERE course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() 
       AND ( 
          (course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%') 
          AND (
             (course_duration IN ('" . $duration1 . "','" . $duration2 . "','" . $duration3 . "') ) 
          OR (course_delivery2 = '" . $delivery2 . "' ) 
          OR (course_guarantee IN ('" . $guarantee1 . "','" . $guarantee2 . "' ) )
          OR (course_city = '" . $city . "')
          OR (course_subc1 = '" . $category1 . "')
          OR (course_subc2 = '" . $category2 . "')
          OR (course_subc3 = '" . $category3 . "')
          OR (course_subc4 = '" . $category4 . "')
          OR (course_subc5 = '" . $category5 . "')
          OR (course_delivery2 = '" . $delivery2 . "')
          OR (course_delivery = '" . $delivery1 . "' )
          )
        ) 
    ORDER BY course_date1 ASC 
    LIMIT  $position, $item_per_page";
```

And now it is much more simple to understand how to add or remove any rule.

So you want to check `course_duration = $duration1` without checking `$_SESSION['userSearch']`? Let's try this way:

```
$get_crs_mysqli = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM courses 
    WHERE course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() 
       AND ( 
          (course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%') 
          AND (
             (course_duration IN ('" . $duration1 . "','" . $duration2 . "','" . $duration3 . "') ) 
          OR (course_delivery2 = '" . $delivery2 . "' ) 
          OR (course_guarantee IN ('" . $guarantee1 . "','" . $guarantee2 . "' ) )
          OR (course_city = '" . $city . "')
          OR (course_subc1 = '" . $category1 . "')
          OR (course_subc2 = '" . $category2 . "')
          OR (course_subc3 = '" . $category3 . "')
          OR (course_subc4 = '" . $category4 . "')
          OR (course_subc5 = '" . $category5 . "')
          OR (course_delivery2 = '" . $delivery2 . "')
          OR (course_delivery = '" . $delivery1 . "' )
          )
          OR (course_duration = '" . $duration1 . "')
        ) 
    ORDER BY course_date1 ASC 
    LIMIT  $position, $item_per_page";
```

**EDIT** According to your comment Iguess you should do more `AND` than `OR`. So we shoudn't  be lazy, and do some work with your variables to prepare query string.

```
$get_crs_mysqli = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM courses 
    WHERE course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() ";

$get_crs_mysqli .= (!empty($_SESSION['userSearch']))?(" AND course_title like '%".$_SESSION['userSearch']."%' ") : '';

$durationArr = array();
if (!empty($duration1)) $durationArr[] = $duration1;
if (!empty($duration2)) $durationArr[] = $duration2;
if (!empty($duration3)) $durationArr[] = $duration3;
if (count($durationArr)>0) {
    $get_crs_mysqli .= " AND  (course_duration IN ('".implode("','", $durationArr)."') ";
 }

$guaranteeArr = array();
if (!empty($guarantee1)) $guaranteeArr[] = $guarantee1;
if (!empty($guarantee2)) $guaranteeArr[] = $guarantee2;
if (count($guaranteeArr)>0) {
    $get_crs_mysqli .= " AND  (course_guarantee IN ('".implode("','", $guaranteeArr)."') ";
 }

$fieldsArr = array();
$fieldsArr['course_delivery2']  = $delivery2;
$fieldsArr['course_city']  = $city;
$fieldsArr['course_subc1']  = $category1;
$fieldsArr['course_subc2']  = $category2;
$fieldsArr['course_subc3']  = $category3;
$fieldsArr['course_subc4']  = $category4;
$fieldsArr['course_subc5']  = $category5;
$fieldsArr['course_delivery2']  = $delivery2;
$fieldsArr['course_delivery']  = $delivery1;
foreach ($fieldsArr as $key=>$val) {
    if (!empty($val)) {
        $get_crs_mysqli .= " AND  $key = $val ";
    }
}

$get_crs_mysqli .= "
    ORDER BY course_date1 ASC 
    LIMIT  $position, $item_per_page";
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification, and yes its more easier that way to view the query. Unfortunatetly, the issue persist where it doesnt seem to populate a different result (get into specific) when an item is checked

Comment: @explain your goal deeper. I guess you don't need those OR. you need them only if some checkbox like (category1, category2 ... etc) is selected? so if 2 checkboxes are selected it must be **AND** but not **OR**?

Comment: exactly. those filters are optional. when the page loads it reads the search query the user has entered and hence the result populated is based on its search. then when the user select a checkbox like category1 or category2 it goes into specifics. example. courses for html are populated, then user checks duration1 so all courses for html with only duration1 is shown if user checks duration1 and 2 then both html courses with duration1 and 2 is shown , and hence number of results shrink. at the start it doesnt take into account the filters, and hence results is larger

Comment: any assistance would be appreciated\

Comment: thank you for all of that. i truly appreciate, sorry but i receive the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' on this line $get_crs_mysqli .= (!empty($_SESSION['userSearch'])?" AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%' " : '';
 i tried to work out that error but that leads to more error

Comment: I notice it was the ? that should have been a closing parenthese, but then when i fix that i get the following error at that line Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" AND course_title like '%"' (

Comment: i then get an error at this line Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$durationArr' (T_VARIABLE) on line 87 which is     $get_crs_mysqli .= " AND  (course_duration IN ('".implode("','"$durationArr)."')) ";

Comment: oops sorry, there is a typo must be like: `IN ('".implode("','", $durationArr)."')) ";`  check updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73864/discussion-between-user3907211-and-alex).

Comment: thank you that resolved this issue, but unfortunatetly i still run into this issue Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" AND course_title like '%"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in at this line $get_crs_mysqli .= (!empty($_SESSION['userSearch']))" AND course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%' " : '';

Comment: try last update `$get_crs_mysqli .= (!empty($_SESSION['userSearch'])?(" AND course_title like '%".$_SESSION['userSearch']."%' ") : '';` did you copy paste my code? you have missed question mark **?** in your comment, but I have that in my post

Comment: thank youvm, but sorry but when i try your last update i get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'  on that line

Comment: this is line i am copy and paste  $get_crs_mysqli .= (!empty($_SESSION['userSearch'])?(" AND course_title like '%".$_SESSION['userSearch']."%' ") : ''; at first i thought the question mark was a typo but i guess its not this the error i am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', almost like the semi-colon at the end is problematic when i know its needed so somewhere within there a typo

Comment: copy again, there was my another typo must be `(!empty($_SESSION['userSearch']))?`

Comment: @user3907211 if you copied my code - there is no error in that line. it must pass in any universe  http://ideone.com/ZcHNPT

Comment: I copied your code, i posted the wrong I am getting. the results does populate for the search query, the problem is that when i hit a checkbox the following error occurs Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: thanks. I was under a lot of pressure today so fail to look critically you have resolved me issue